# static variables in a window procedure

Tags: c, winapi, static

I created a static variable in a window procedure of dialog. When this dialog is closed (but the application is still running), is the static variable `hwndChildDialog` is deleted and its memory address is free? If not, should I and how to do this clean?

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK Dialog_Preference_Proc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

{
    static HWND hwndChildDialog = CreateDialog(...);

}
```

Comment: It is not.  Nor is the dialog you create with it released.  Using WM_INITDIALOG would be the smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` keyword in C creates the variable at some place on the 'static memory', meaning: the address of the variable never changes over the lifespan of the program, it's position in the memory is 'static' (hence the keyword). So, no matter when or from where you access the variable: it is always the same instance of it.

Its memory address doesn't get free'd.

In this case, you don't have to do anything to free a "CreateDialog", you only have to ShowWindow and DestroyWindow.

Comment: a 'static' variable is not 'global', it is created at the 'static' part of the memory (meaning 'not heap' and 'not stack which will make the variable vanish after leaving the current scope'). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable ... and a variable on the stack gets freed automatically after leaving the current scope.

Comment: @akira, I think Keith's description of "like global and only visible in one function" was a good way to describe it.

Comment: @akira, thats why I said its "basically" a global, for all intense purposes, its a global thats only visible within a function scope.  stack variables aren't really a "resource".  They are just variables within scopes, outside of the scope they just disappear  (doesn't really matter if they are on the stack or not, in fact, sometimes they are just in registers)

Comment: it's "global" in the same sense as all memory: give me a pointer and i dangle it :) or in the same sense as all "strings" are "global" coz they end up in the same .text section. i just think that the description of "static" is a bit sloppy.

Comment: it more meant to be conceptual than pedantic :)

Comment: a sloppy explained concept leads to a sloppy understanding :)

Comment: static's and globals are in the same (type of) memory region. They are just different in how they are visible to other components.